# Upgrade caused webcam to malfunction

Tags: drivers, webcam, toshiba-laptop

I have a 3 year old Toshiba Satellite A305-S6857 an it came pre-installed with Windows Vista. (Quite the bummer I know). However through school I was able to upgrade my OS to Windows 7.

However in the process something funky happened: I completely lost the driver for the functionality of my webcam. I tried calling Toshiba and much to my surprise, Warranty is out so all they could tell me to do was to download the drivers from their site. This unfortunately did not work as they did not have the appropriate driver for my webcam.

After extensive search online I found the driver for my webcam. I installed it on my laptop hoping that this would restore my functionality. Unfortunately every time I try to start up the webcam with the software I get the following message...

> Webcam is either disabled or has failed. Please check your webcam setting.

How do I even begin to check its settings if the computer doesn't even recognize the webcam within the device manager. Any suggestions on what I could do to restore the functionality of the webcam?

Answer (score 1):

Try scanning for new hardware. In addition, see if your driver is really installed. If it is, try to use some third party software to access the webcam ([avacam](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/RGS-AvaCam.shtml) or something similar)

Comment: It appears as though my driver is not installed. However, I cannot find a driver installation for this webcab anywhere.